# default magento onepage checkout success page gives 404 error

Tags: magento-1.9, onepage-checkout, customer-session

I am using Magento 1.9.2.4 and default onepage checkout. I am facing issue when customer already on checkout page and click on place order but session was got timeout before placing order. Below is scenario:

My session time out set from backend is 3600sec.

1. I am on checkout page and on order review step and selected COD payment method
2. I waited for 1hr then I clicked on place order button, My order got placed and redirect to checkout/onepage/success and throws 404 because customer session was timed out.

If I visit this url http://domain.com/checkout/onepage/success directly in address bar if customer is not logged then magento throwing 404 error page.

I have configure in backend **system > configuration > checkout > allow guest checkout > No**
and **system > configuration  > checkout > Require Customer To Be Logged In To Checkout > Yes**

When I changed **Yes** to **No** for **Require Customer To Be Logged In To Checkout** then it's working fine.

Why Magento treating success page url as 404 error page when customer session timed out and setting for **Require Customer To Be Logged In To Checkout** is set to **Yes**?

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Finally, I figured out root cause.
Every questions answered by following `preDispatch()` function written in `OnepageController` (`app\code\core\Mage\Checkout\controllers\OnepageController.php`)

```
    if (!$this->_canShowForUnregisteredUsers()) {
        $this->norouteAction();
        $this->setFlag('',self::FLAG_NO_DISPATCH,true);
        return;
    }
```

If you further look into `_canShowForUnregisteredUsers()` function

```
protected function _canShowForUnregisteredUsers()
{
    return Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn()
        || $this->getRequest()->getActionName() == 'index'
        || Mage::helper('checkout')->isAllowedGuestCheckout($this->getOnepage()->getQuote())
        || !Mage::helper('checkout')->isCustomerMustBeLogged();
}
```

This code is checking following configuration:

```
 system > configuration > checkout > allow guest checkout > No
 system > configuration > checkout > Require Customer To Be Logged In To Checkout > Yes
```

So `checkout/onepage/success` is not allowed for unregistered user, so **`norouteAction()`** method redirecting to 404 error page.

To fix this issue if you are using above settings then you can override `preDispatch()` method of checkout onepage controller or writing `Observer` to check checkout `preDispatch` event and write needed code. [check here for list of Magento events.](https://www.nicksays.co.uk/magento-events-cheat-sheet-1-8/)